# spring boot can't import package which in same project but different folder

Tags: java, spring-boot

Here is my project structure

```
appName
 --- model
     --- src
         ---- main
              --- basePackageName
                  ---packageOne
 --- service
    --- src
        ---- main
             ---- basePackageName
                  ---packageTwo
```

I want to use packageOne in my packageTwo, and i can import packageOne properly when I was on spring boot version 2.1.6.RELEASE but after upgraded to 2.6.7, all packageOne imports are greyed out and gradle build gave me a symbol can't resolve error as it thinks packageOne doesn't exist.

I have made sure the @SpringBootApplication annotation is there and both packageOne and packageTwo share same prefix:com.example.packageOne and com.example.packageTwo.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    }
}
```

any thoughts are welcomed, thanks.

Comment: What IDE are you using? In case of IntelliJ, did you try to repair it?

Comment: Package visibility rules are not related to the version of Spring Boot: they depends on the classpath of Java only so there is certainly some other change you have made.